Convexity implies weak semi lower continuity
Let $V$ be a Hilbert space, $\mu : V \rightarrow \mathcal{C}_0^2(\mathbb{R}^d)'$ a continuous linear map.
I want to study the existence of minima of $$J(v) = \Vert \mu(v) - w \Vert^2 + \Vert v \Vert_V^2$$ for $w \in \mathcal{C}_0^2(\mathbb{R}^d)'$
I showed that J is continous and convex by composition and sum. I would like to use the direct method as described here.
So i took a minimizing sequence $(v_n)$ for J and using Banach-Alaoglu, it admits a subsequence $(v_{n_k}) $ that weakly converges to $v^\infty \in V$. Now, i want to show that J is sequentially weakly lower semi-continuous.
I tried this :
Since $\mu$ is linear and also are the norms, then J is differentiable. So, for $v \in V$, we can define the gradient $\nabla J(v)$ by Riesz Theorem.
We consider $v_n \rightharpoonup v$. Then, by convexity
$J(v_n)\geq J(v) + \langle \nabla J(v) , v_n-v\rangle$.
Finally, $\operatorname{lim inf} J(v_n)\geq J(v)$, so J is weakly lower semi continuous.
Is this proof legit ? The two main points i'm not confident about are the differentiability of J (and the existence of the gradient), and the fact that continuous $\Rightarrow$ weak semi-lower continuity.

How is $J$ convex? Are there some special properties of $\mu$ that you are using?

Using the linearity of $\mu$ no ?
$J(t v + (1-t) u) = \Vert t \mu(v) + (1-t) \mu(u) - tw -  (1-t)w \Vert^2 + \Vert t v + (1-t) u \Vert^2 =  \Vert t (\mu(v) -w) + (1-t) (\mu(u) - w) \Vert^2 + \Vert t v + (1-t) u \Vert^2 $. Then i use the convexity of the squared norm to get the result.

Weak and strong lower semicontinuity are actually equivalent for convex maps by the Hahn-Banach theorem: A map is lower semicontinuous iff the sublevel sets are closed. By convexity, the sublevel sets are convex. By Hahn-Banach, the weak and strong closure of convex sets coincide. Now need to use differentiability. (I did not check the details of your proof. Might still be valid.)

@MaoWao If i understand what you said, i could prove this result by the following way :
I want to show that J is sequentially weakly semi-lower continuous. By Hahn-Banach, it's equivalent to show that J is sequentially s.l.c. Then i consider $v_n \rightarrow v$, and since J is continuous, $\lim J(v_n)= J(v)$, so $\lim J(v_n)=\liminf J(v_n) = J(v)$. Finally, i can conclude that $\liminf J(v_n)\geq J(v)$ which proves that J is sequentially l.s.c ?

@Cantor Muyapologies, I missed the linear in the statement.

No worries. Actually J is strictly convex

@Cantor That's right. Continuity always implies lower semicontinuity (for the same topology).

Note that $\operatorname{epi} J$ is closed and convex hence weakly closed. Since $J \ge 0$, and $J(v) \ge \|v\|^2$, we see that $C = \{ (v,\eta) \in \operatorname{epi} J | \eta \le J(0) \}$ is a weakly compact set that contains any minimisers. Since the functional $\phi((v,\eta)) = \eta$ is weakly continuous, there is some $(v^*, \eta^*) \in C$ that minimises $\phi$, and we must have $J(v^*) = \eta^*$.
Elaborations:
Suppose $v^*$ is a minimiser of $J$, then $J(v^*) \le J(0)$ and so $(v^*, J(v^*)) \in C$.
Since $C$ is bounded Banach Alaoglu tells us that it is relatively weak compact, and since it is also weakly closed, it is compact.
A continuous function on a compact set attains its extreme values.

$\operatorname{epi} J$ is closed because J is continuous so in particular semi-lower continuous ? Can you detail the part "C is a weakly compact set that contains any minimisers" please ? I dont really get it

@Cantor Your question is a little broad. I added some elaborations above, hopefully that addresses your question.
